# Send form to multiple emails using get_option() (Wordpress)

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms, email

I have a form in my wordpress site, and I would like to have it sent to two emails. Both of them can be edited on my settings page. I'm trying to use get_option() with two values, but the email is only sent to the first one.

The two fields have been created using add_settings_section() on my functions file.

This is what my code looks like:

```
if(!isset($hasError)) {
        $emailTo = get_option('main_email', 'other_email');
        if (!isset($emailTo) || ($emailTo == '') ){
            $emailTo = get_option('admin_email');
        }

        $subject = '...';
        $body = '...'
        $headers = 'From: '.$individualName.' <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $individualEmail;

        wp_mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
        $emailSent = true;
}
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter of the get_option function is a value which will be returned if the option does not exist or it's empty.

You could do something like this

```
if(!isset($hasError)) {

    $emailTo = get_option('main_email' );

    if ( ! $emailTo ){
        $emailTo = get_option('other_email', get_option('admin_email'));
    }
```